# Opening VPF DNC's Notes in GDAL?

Tags: gis, gdal

I use a compiled version of GDAL, including OGDI lib :

- GDAL 2.0.1
- OGDI 3.1.6

I can open DNC Charts and retrieve layers / features.
DNC Charts use VPF format.

Problem : I’m not able to retrieve notes which can be found in NOTES.RAT and NOTES.NJT, like explained in this VPF specification :

[VECTOR PRODUCT FORMAT (VPF) products General Specification](http://earth-info.nga.mil/publications/specs/printed/vpf/int_milprf0089049.pdf)

3.16.4.2.1.1 Notes related attribute tables

Have you got any idea about this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with the OGDI lib developer, there is no way to get notes using OGDI (for the moment).
You must decode binary files (notes.rat, notes.njt) according to VPF specification : 
[VECTOR PRODUCT FORMAT (VPF) products General Specification](http://earth-info.nga.mil/publications/specs/printed/vpf/int_milprf0089049.pdf)